# Spring Boot OAuth2 Resource Server - Difficulty Making Publicly Accessible Paths

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am experimenting with Spring Boot Security OAuth2. I would like to make some paths publicly accessible; that is, not requiring authentication. However, I am receiving the following error:

`{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}`

PublicController

```
    @RequestMapping("/public")
public class PublicController {
    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

Now, normally this would be a good thing (since security is the goal), but, I have explicitly told the application to permitAll() on that path.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import com.midamcorp.resource_server.service.OAuthUserDetailsService;


@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private OAuthUserDetailsService userService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
}

    // Hash password
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
       .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/public/**")
       .permitAll()
       .and()
              .sessionManagement()
               .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
               .and()
               .httpBasic()
               .realmName("test")
               .and()
               .csrf()
               .disable();

    }
}
```

I have tried various combinations, including using antMatches(/**) and removing the portions after the and(). However, I still receive the same error.

Thanks.

EDIT:

ResourceServerConfig

```
@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConifig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

     private final AppConfig appConfig; 

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public  ResourceServerConifig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, AppConfig appConfig) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.appConfig = appConfig;
    }


    @Bean
    @Primary //Making this primary to avoid any accidental duplication with another token service instance of the same name
   ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.tokenServices(tokenServices());
    }   


}
```

ApplicationConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class AppConfig {

       @Bean
       public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        //  return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
           return new JwtTokenStore((jwtTokenEnhancer()));
       }


        @Bean
        protected JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtTokenEnhancer() {
            JwtAccessTokenConverter converter =  new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
            Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("public.cert");
            String publicKey = null;
            try {
                publicKey = new String(FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(resource.getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
            return converter;
        }

}
```

Comment: I guess all three configuration are in the same web app. So you have to change the order and matchers. By default resource server configuration has order 3 and matches `/**`.  Your custom configuration has order 100 and matches `/**`. So only one is applied.

Comment: Since using JWT, does this app even need the additional AppConfig and SecurityConfig?  Only the ResourceServerConfig is needed.  Everything else is handled by the AuthorizationServer generating the JWT tokens.

Comment: The @EnableResourceServer doesn't need TokenStore, TokenServices or AuthenticationManager.

Comment: @dur changing the order (via the `@Order(n) `annotation) did resolve the issue. Thanks for the insight and thanks DaShaun for your help too.

Answer (score -1):

In your application.yml you could add this:

```
security:
  ignored: /public,/public/**
```

Comment: Thanks, but adding `security.ignored=/public,/public/**` to my application.properties did not resolve the issue (which surprised me a bit).

Comment: Spring Boot's configuration is overriden with `@EnableWebSecurity`, so the properties should not change anything.